# Is there a Heroku-supported method for getting the length of an audio file in seconds?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, audio, heroku, ffmpeg, mp3

I'm trying to implement

http://blog.firmhouse.com/validate-length-of-an-audio-file-when-using-paperclip-and-s3

But I'm unsure what gem provided FFMpegWrapper, and I'd like to use Heroku to deploy my app for testing.  Does heroku support something that will work for this?

full Rails Application source:

https://github.com/mrgenixus/sound-byte

Relevant Model:

https://github.com/mrgenixus/sound-byte/blob/master/app/models/episode.rb

Comment: I'm thinking this might get me closer: https://gist.github.com/3963576

Answer (score 1):

Long time ago, but this helped me out:

```
https://github.com/streamio/streamio-ffmpeg

audio = FFMPEG::Movie.new("path/to/audio.mp3")
audio.duration # 7.5 (duration of the audiofile in seconds)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm working on the same kind of app (you can see here - https://github.com/taelor/radio) and I have this exact same question.

Now, I also needed to use wkhtmltopdf, so I just put it in app/bin/wkhtmltopdf and could point wicked_pdf to that binary. I'm going to experiment with it and get back to you.